# inputFile.current.click() inside useEffect doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, recoiljs

I have `<input type="file" />` and want to trigger `.click()` on that input.
Everything works fine in chrome, firefox, edge but problem exists in safari.

When I click on button to trigger  `inputFile.current.click()` - it works.
But when it happens inside useEffect/useLayoutEffect - it doesn't work (I've tried adding timeouts and it also didn't help).

Working example to reproduce problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-49n2t?file=/src/index.js

As less code as possible to present problem

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
import { requestedNewCanvasObjAtom } from '../SlidesState/slidesAtoms';

const Slide: React.FC = () => {
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false);
  const [requestedNewCanvasObj] = useRecoilState(requestedNewCanvasObjAtom);
  const inputFile = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log('IT IS HERE WHEN EXPECTED BUT IT DOES NOT WORK TOO');
    inputFile.current.click();
  }, [requestedNewCanvasObj]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log('IT WORKS');
    inputFile.current.click();
  }, [trigger]);

  const triggerUpload = useCallback(() => {
    if (inputFile && inputFile.current) {
      console.log('IT WORKS');
      inputFile.current.click();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={triggerUpload}>Click</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTrigger(true)}>Update state to trigger input click</button>
      <input type="file" id="file" ref={inputFile} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Slide;
```

THIS QUESTION WAS UPDATED -
simplified problem without recoil was solved by useLayoutEffect but turns out that my problem is more complex

Answer (score 5):

The on click event is fired but the finder doesn't show up. Use [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect). It fires synchronously after all DOM mutations:

```
  useLayoutEffect(()=> {
    if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.click();
    }
  }, [count])
```

In other browsers like `Chrome`, `useEffects` and `useLayoutEffect` will work to show the finder. But in `Safari`, only the `useLayoutEffect` will work.

Comment: Thank you - it works in my example, but turns out that it doesn't work in my project. I'm updating question.

Comment: @Żywy Do you have some working example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I've just created it: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-49n2t?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

@Żywy Add `id` to **input** and add **label** with `htmlFor` attribute.

**Important**: Input element must not be inside the **label**

Check this codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-7bnut7?file=/src/index.js (click on the red text)